# Top tab bar for Xamarin.iOS+MVVMCross

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

What is the most effective way to implement a top bar like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbGRY.png) for Xamarin iOS + MVVMCross? I've successfully done it for Android using MvxTabLayoutPresentation, but for iOS I get a bottom tab bar instead.

Comment: It is a Material Design idiom, doesn't fit nice on iOS. You should probably avoid it or use a Segmented Control

Comment: Segmented control is exactly what I need. Thank you very much.